# Pass data on URL in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to display the data in my recyclerview that come from a json data, but Im getting null pointer exception , I dont know where did I do wrong from it.

this is my json data:

{
    "value": 1,
    "review_profile_results": [
        {
            "review_id": "1",
            "review_name": "Sample",
            "review_user_id": "2",
            "review_comments": "+ Reputation, trusted",
            "review_rate": "4",
            "review_rate_def": "Trusted",
            "review_date": "2018-07-22 06:17:31"
        }
    ]
}

This is for API interface:

```
@GET (UrlFinal.pathServiceUrl+"show_profile_reviews.php")
Call <Value> show_profileReviews (@Query("id")String id);
```

possible URL result that I want to pass

`/show_profile_reviews.php?id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b`

This is for how I passing the data

```
 private void showProfileReviews(){
    String userId = MainActivity.user.getId();

    String id_md5 = md5(userId);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), id_md5, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder ()
            .baseUrl (UrlFinal.ipUrl)
            .addConverterFactory (GsonConverterFactory.create ())
            .build ();
    ServiceAPI api = retrofit.create (ServiceAPI.class);
    Call<Value> call = api.show_profileReviews(id_md5);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Value>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Value> call, @NonNull Response<Value> response) {
            if (Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getValue() == 1) {
                profile_list = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getReviewProfileResults();
                adapter = new Adapter_ProfileReviews(getActivity(), profile_list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Log.d("Result", profile_list.toString());
                Log.d("Result", call.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Value> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Result", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}


public String md5(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest));

        return hexString.toString();
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the `NullPointerException`? Consider logging`call.request().url()` to check if URL is correct before enqueuing the call. Then inside `onResponse` callback, check if response `isSsuccessful()` instead of calling `requireNonNull` , if not, log some information about the response (error code, error body).

Comment: @Ollaw It's okay now, thanks for your answer call.request().url I figure it now

Answer (score 0):

You have a base url for your retrofit client, so define your interface as follows,

```java
public interface YourApiInterface {  
    @GET ("/show_profile_reviews")
    Call <Value> show_profileReviews (@Query("id")String id);
}
```

Retrofit call will then be, **BASE_URL/show_profile_reviews?id=your_id**

If you want to use a dynamic URL then define your interface as follows,

```java
public interface YourApiInterface {  
    @GET
    Call <Value> show_profileReviews (@Url String url);
}
```

If you use dynamic url then you can pass the Url as,

```java
apiInterface.show_profileReviews("https://base_url/show_profile_reviews.php?id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b");
```

**For more**,
http://square.github.io/retrofit/